# Htaccess rewrite no extension or slash

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want every file on my server like this
"mywebsite.com/video?id=vgIjgt863_53", 
I have php so at the moment it would look like this
"mywebsite.com/video.php?id=(id)"
I need this in htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your htaccess in root folder with this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^video$ /video.php?id=%1 [L]
```